# Dropzone JS Wait until ajax form submitted and change options.url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dropzone.js

I have Rails application with dropzonejs plugin to upload images.
I'm creating `Album` right before image is uploaded.
Then I want to upload picture to a new album.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) {
    # Performing album creation via $.ajax
    # $.ajax return ID of an album, but JS already skipped before I set new URL
    });
  }
};
```

How can I wait until request is done and properly set returned ID as url option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use accept in this case -

```js
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  accept: function(file, done)
        {
            file.postData = {};
            $.ajax({
                url: '/album',
                data: {name: file.name, type: file.type},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response)
                {
                    file.album_id = response.album_id;
                    done();
                },
                error: function(response)
                {
                    done('error preparing the file');
                }
            });
        },
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) {
      # Do other stuffs if needed
    });
  }
};
```

Now, dropbox will wait until drop() is called.

Comment: This is supposed to work. I have used this inside my project. :)